# C# toolstrip dropdown button text box validate on enter key?

Tags: c#, validation, textbox, enter, toolstrip

I have a toolstrip dropdownbutton which contains textbox in the dropdown menu. I'm trying to make it fire Validate event properly when an Enter key is pressed.

I have this simple code:

```
    private void txtSourceUrl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == Convert.ToChar(Keys.Enter))
        {
            txtSourceUrl_Validated(null, null);
        }
    }
```

Which works, But, it still makes the Windows sound for "improper input" (that "ding!") play, which is unfortunate. I don't know how to get rid of it, or how to do it properly, as this method I'm using seems to be kind of a hack.

I searched the text box properties, but there seems to be nothing related in there (AcceptsReturn doesn't work as text boxes in the dropdown can't be multiline). 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `e.Handled = true` in the event handler.

*UPDATE*

To avoid confusion, this answers the question how to get rid of the sound on Enter. Answers to [combo box not validating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13938073/combo-box-not-validating) confirm the general approach and give another idea.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: What to you consider to be the question? I read "how to get rid of ... the Windows sound for improper input" which I answered.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I misinterpreted the question. My apologies.

Comment: Alright. I also edited my answer to indicate which part of the question it answers.